# How to create an autocomplete list in Sublime Text for common Python lines?

Tags: python, sublimetext2, sublimetext

Can I define an "autocomplete list" file in Sublime Text 2, with one item per line:

```
autocomplete.txt
######
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
...
```

such that, when writing:

<kbd>i</kbd> <kbd>m</kbd> <kbd>p</kbd> <kbd>TAB</kbd>

it automatically suggests `import numpy as np`, when hitting <kbd>TAB</kbd> again, it would suggest `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`, etc.

I would like this to be available in every Sublime Text document, even a new blank .py file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to achieve something like this is a [sublime-completions file](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/completions.html). These function similarly to [snippets](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/snippets.html#snippets) but allow you to specify multiple completions in the same file instead of requiring one file for each. They're better suited to this usage because they work best for smaller bits of code, whereas snippets excel at bigger blocks of text.

An example file based on your question would look like the following. To try it out, create a file named `MyCompletions.sublime-completions` in your `User` package; use `Preferences > Browse Packages...` if you're not sure where that is.

```json
{
    "scope": "source.python",

    "completions": [
        "import numpy as np",
        "import matplotlib.pyplot as plt"
    ]
}
```